# Error connecting to Cloud SQL with SSL using Debezium

Tags: mysql, ssl, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

**Objective**: To use debezium to capture changes from Cloud SQL. The instance of Cloud SQL is SSL enabled according to the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance)

**Scenario**: I have debezium connect, kafka and zookpeer running as docker containers on my local machine. I have tested the setup against a Cloud SQL instance without SSL. Things are working. Once I enable SSL, convert the pem files (`server-ca.pem`, `client-cert.pem`, `client-key.pem`) to keystore and truststore, mount them as files in the debezium connect docker container, I get an error in Debezium container logs as such (after sending the POST request to the endpoint):

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error reading MySQL variables: Access denied for user 'user'@'redacted_my_ip' (using password: YES)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlJdbcContext.querySystemVariables(MySqlJdbcContext.java:297)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlJdbcContext.readMySqlSystemVariables(MySqlJdbcContext.java:278)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlTaskContext.<init>(MySqlTaskContext.java:81)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlTaskContext.<init>(MySqlTaskContext.java:53)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.createAndStartTaskContext(MySqlConnectorTask.java:331)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:136)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'redacted_my_ip' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$1(JdbcConnection.java:179)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:756)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:751)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connect(JdbcConnection.java:298)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlJdbcContext.querySystemVariables(MySqlJdbcContext.java:284)
    ... 14 more
```

**My preliminary analysis**: I have been going through the TRACE logs and the source code. According to the logs, it is able to successfully test the connection

```
2019-04-10 10:11:45,777 INFO   ||  Successfully tested connection for jdbc:mysql://redacted_ip:3306/?useInformationSchema=true&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=false&useSSL=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL with user 'user'   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector]
```

This log is generated right after [line 101](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/f04147d67daa2f9747ea5b33629b74ff1b59a9ed/debezium-connector-mysql/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mysql/MySqlConnector.java#L101)

Here we execute a query on the database, which only on successful execution will let the control flow to the log. This according to me implies that debezium connect is able to connect to the database, but fails at some other place. According to the stack trace, debezium fails to connect the second time, [here](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/f04147d67daa2f9747ea5b33629b74ff1b59a9ed/debezium-connector-mysql/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mysql/MySqlJdbcContext.java#L286)

The payload that I am sending is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "connector-test",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "MySql",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "redacted_ip",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "user",
        "database.password": "redacted_user_password",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory",
        "database.ssl.mode": "required",
        "database.ssl.keystore": "./keystore",
        "database.ssl.keystore.password": "redacted_keystore_password",
        "database.ssl.truststore": "./truststore",
        "database.ssl.truststore.password": "redacted_truststore_password"
    }
}
```

What steps are needed in order to get the above setup working

Comment: The correspondents catch block catches a SQLException, so it shouldn't be an error related to the connection. Can you post the statement that would be passed to the ‘querySystemVariables’ method?

Comment: According to the code, it should executes `SHOW VARIABLES`. I tried executing the same query from a sample java app with the same user, password, keystore, truststore. It works fine. So the user surely has the required permissions to execute the query. I also executed the same query through a mysql client (again from the same user), and that worked too.
I was suspecting it to be a query related error too. But the other things i tried (mentioned above) make me question if it actually is because of the query.

Comment: This is a bug. It has been reported [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1228)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed and now merged on the master branch with this [PR](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/pull/867)